# customizing docker-compose.yml for images from docker store

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i'm new to docker and i'm currently experimenting using https://github.com/diginc/docker-pi-hole

It's pretty straightforward if i just imagine it as a light-weight VM, i've pulled the image using `docker pull diginc/pi-hole` and manually started the image by doing

```
docker run -d \
    --name pi-hole \
    -p 53:53/tcp 
    -p 53:53/udp 
    -p 8053:80 \
    -e TZ=SG \
    -v "/Users/me/pihole/:/etc/pihole/" \
    -v "/Users/me/dnsmasq.d/:/etc/dnsmasq.d/" \
    -e ServerIP="192.168.0.25" \
    --restart=always \
    diginc/pi-hole:alpine
```

everything works well, but in their documentation, it's mentioned to use `docker_run.sh`

No idea where/how to execute this, and also the authors also suggested using docker-compose, but after pulling the project, i can't find where's the actual directory.

- Where is the directory?
- What's the typical way of customizing the compose.yml
- How to run after i've done my customization?

Answer (score 2):

The docker-run.sh is on the site

https://github.com/diginc/docker-pi-hole/blob/master/docker_run.sh

Just use it

Comment: Do `git clone https://github.com/diginc/docker-pi-hole` and you have all the code available locally